# Laravel 5.4 printing out a seating plan

Tags: php, mysql, loops, laravel-5

I have an sql table of seats with the columns (id,row, seat_number). Im trying to print out the seats something like this,

```
A 1,2,3
B 4,5,6
C 7,8,9
```

I've managed to do this by hard coding if statements for each row, like so

```
    @if($row->rw==='A')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">{{$row->rw}}</div>
            @foreach($seats as $seat)
               @if($seat->rw === 'A')
                  {{$seat->number}}
               @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
```

What I would like to know is a better method that doesn't require me to hard code each row. I'm guessing it would be some loop that would go through and check the row for unique character and print the seat_numbers in that row.

I'm fairly new to laravel and php as I'm sure you can tell, any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what the controller looks like

```
public function view($id)
{

    $rooms = Room::findOrFail($id);

    $rows = Seat::distinct()->get(['rw']);

    $seats = Seat::all();

    return view('admin.rooms.view', compact('rooms','rows', 'seats'));

}
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what the `$row` and `$seats` data looks like

Comment: `@if($seat->rw === $row->rw)` See if that works, given that `$row` is a result of looping through `$rows`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you